# Error when opening Jupyter Notebook from terminal on Mac

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I get the following error when trying to open a Jupyter Notebook (using the command jupyter notebook) from the terminal on mac.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1531, in initialize
    super(NotebookApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-6>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 242, in initialize
    self.migrate_config()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 168, in migrate_config
    migrate()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/migrate.py", line 247, in migrate
    with open(os.path.join(env['jupyter_config'], 'migrated'), 'w') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Mridula/.jupyter/migrated'
```

I have tried to uninstall and re-install. I still face the same error. I have tried to clear the bash profile, to no avail.

Any help would be highly welcome and appreciated.

Best, 
Mridula

Comment: you have permission issues. Change the owner and the permission of your anaconda directory.

Comment: Any advice on how I can do that?

Comment: I made the permission changes, I am still unable to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you please tell me the steps you followed to install and run the notebook? You can add them at the end of your question.

Comment: Also, are you using Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: I downloaded the Anaconda distribution and Python. And then I installed both and then ran the command jupyter notebook on my terminal. It worked once and then stopped working. After which I tried to re-install but it did not work.

Comment: If I try to open it using the Navigator, I get the same error.

Comment: Can you try to uninstall it and remove the directory .jupyter from your user? Then freshly install and run it again.

Comment: Okay, I will try that and get back to you. Thank you very much!

Comment: I uninstalled Anaconda and then removed the .Jupyter directory through root access and it finally worked!

Comment: Good job! I just summarized our convo as an answer to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm summarizing our conversations here as it helped you to resolve the problem.

There could be many possible options to address this issue. However, the very first approach to tackle this problem is to resolve permission issues. The last line of your error message is `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Mridula/.jupyter/migrated'` which means you don't have the right permission to access the `.jupyter` directory.

Change file permission

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /Users/Mridula/.jupyter/
```

If this doesn't help then do the following steps

- uninstall Anaconda
- remove .jupyter directory from your user
- install a fresh copy of Anaconda

Hope it helps!